# Can't display empty Table View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm following the Apple tutorial on how to develop iOS apps.

At some point tutorial tells me to add a `table view controller` to my story board and change the arrow of the `story board entry point` to point to that one.

I do it save and run. A blank screen shows up. In the tutorial they say it should show an empty table with emtpy rows.

Simulator on iPhone 6. (iPhone 6S and above seems to work)

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your project now sure what is wrong. I just created a new project and added a Table View Controller and set it as the InitialViewController and it works. Make sure in the attributes inspector ( on the right hand side of Xcode that the box is checked that says " is initial View Controller" and you should get an empty table view with empty rows when you run it in the simulator

Comment: Thanks! I tried the same now (created a new project and tried it out). I found out that on the simultator with iPhone 6S it works (rows are shown). However, on the iPhone 6, it doesn't (blank screen).

Comment: That is weird, I will look into that but ignore the below comment, on constraints, if you are using a TableViewController everything is set up for you concerning constraints so that wouldn't be the issue

Comment: The simulator smoothes the graphics or better rendering performance (you can set that in the menu somewhere). Depending on monitor dimensions, scaling of the simulator and plain position this sometimes makes the lines between cells disappear. Have you tried pulling the table? If it bounces you should still see that. Also note that a really "blank" screen would be black (a window's background color is). A "white blank" screen usually means some view is displayed. Also check the view hierarchy debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Set the tableViews constraints to the top, bottom, and both sides of its containing view. Then right click the tableView and drag onto the yellow button on the top left of the viewController. Hit delegate, then do it again and hit datasource. Then try to run the project.

Comment: He is using a TableViewController, without doing anything he should see an empty Table on the screen without adding delegate nor datasource.

Comment: He doesn't see it though. So in case he somehow had a single constraint set I told him to do this. I am very aware of what he should see, but I am troubleshooting with him without having to ask him questions.